# Is it possible to demonstrate being God without using any power?

Tags: religion, gods

God is on Earth and is trying to convince someone without using any power.

How?

A power is anything that no human can do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91322/discussion-on-question-by-malkev-is-it-possible-to-demonstrate-being-god-without).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Pretty tricky to do really. In fact, I don't believe it's possible.**

You may be able to empirically test that its construction is not biologically possible (or, perhaps, biological at all). Presumably a being capable of the miracles of God would have a physical form that defies known physics. This is not a 'power' of God as it is simply a fundamental of its existence.

This lends weight to its assertions that it is God, but is not in itself proof. It could also be true that it is a [sufficiently advanced alien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) and/or that our understanding of physics is not yet complete.

In fact, demonstration of Godly power would likewise be explainable via Clarke's Third Law (or, rather, Sherman's Law). Proving something is God is tricky even without restrictions.

For reference Sherman's Law is: 'Any sufficiently advanced alien is indistinguishable from god.'

Comment: Intricate knowledge could be considered a power, so that could fall through. I agree with Clarke's Third Law, hence the upvote.

Comment: @DarthDonut You might be right about the intricate knowledge thing, although understanding how the universe works is within the scope of human understanding so I didn't view it as a 'power'. That is making assumptions about how much we can work out of course. The same could be true of any other power God is ascribed of course (we don't know our limits!).

Comment: "intricate knowledge" as described would be beyond what any one human could know, thus a power (even DaVinci didn't know everything) and being biologically different than humans could make him a frog or a goat.  This was a good stab, but it needs a deeper think-through.

Comment: @JBH My real point is that even the most likely possible empirical options are unable to provide proof (biological difference, intrinsic knowledge). I don't actually believe it is possible, due to Clarke's Third Law (or, rather, Sherman's Law), but if I were to try I'd do these, with the testing of biology as a first port of call.

Comment: In other words, this is a [frame challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7097)?  If you turn this into a frame challenge, I'll happily upvote it.  Right now, it's a non-answer, almost a comment.

Comment: @JBH Had a go at rewording it ;) what do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I'm especially delighted with the observation that god doesn't have "powers" (as if god were nothing more than a superhero) but that his/her abilities are "fundamental of its existence" (a butterfly's ability to fly vs my inability to fly).  Good work.

Comment: @JBH No, thank you for the feedback ;) and glad you like it!

Answer (score 3):

**Looks and following.**

A heavenly host of [mal'āk̠ 'ĕlōhîm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel#Judaism) would throng around praising a Hebrew God.

[Angels and Archangels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel#Christianity) the same with a Christian one.

[Malak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel#Islam) to an Islamic one.

... and so on with Zoroastrianism, Sikhism etc.

**Other gods are more conspicuous by their very nature.**

When having a weekend in the Lake district Godspotting, it's important to bring your field guide to god identification. Watch out for the occasional rare specimens.

[Shiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva#Forms_and_depictions) - three eyes, four arms, covered in ash etc..

[Ganesha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha) - very well dressed, talking, elephant.

[Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor) - big hammer, big muscles, slow wit, quick to anger if you point that out to him. Speaks archaic Norse.

[Proteus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteus) - in natural form (not using protean powers) has a fish tail.

Comment: Good idea, but what I'm struggling with in my answer too is Clarke's Third Law. How does anything we can measure provide evidence that a being is God, rather than a sufficiently advanced alien (and is there even a difference)?

Comment: @Ynneadwraith I suspect that ultimatley "proof" becomes moot and that one needs to have faith :-/ There's loads of books speculating the Alien origins of Jesus - some even older than me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariots_of_the_Gods%3F

Comment: Now that's a truth. I suspect that ultimately, 'proof' is *currently* moot when it comes to the perceived existence or non-existence of God. I perceive no likely change if someone turned up one day claiming to be God/the messiah. From what I gather that happens periodically in real life too.

Answer (score 0):

It really only takes the power of persuasion. Many religions have been founded simply by a person being able to persuade others that he or she is the Annointed, the Deity Incarnate or even the Second Coming of Christ. This is especially true of cult religions which are multitudinous and various.

One aspect of the being attempting to demonstrate its deityhood without actually doing anything is its appearance. The OP's question doesn't give any clues to this aspect. Appearance alone might be sufficient for people to believe they have encountered a god.

This might come to something as simple as wearing a name tag with the label "I AM GOD".

Although descending from the Heavens on a beam of light might be dead giveaway.

Comment: "descending from the Heavens on a beam of light" *is* a miracle. And having extremely good looks doesn't *demonstrate* anything. There are plenty of people with extremely good looks. Unless there is some supernatural quality in those good looks, of course. But then we are back to God using his powers...

Comment: @cmaster The beam of light bit was a joke.Geddit! As for 'extremely good looks', nope. I only suggested this being might have an appearance that spelled out their divinity. On the other hand, someone with exceptional good looks & exceptional powers of persuasion, with human bounds, could persuade people it was a god. Many people can be easily persuaded about almost anything.

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference between the incarnate God, and a human? *The only difference is, that the God can do stuff that a human can't.* What he does is up to him, it can be stark miracles like fire falling from heaven, or subtle ones like precise knowledge of a person's past without ever having met him/her before. But it must be something that a human cannot do. Because otherwise, Occam's razor tells us to assume he's just a human. As such, God cannot prove himself without demonstrating supernatural powers.

Btw, that's precisely why Christians think that the miracles that Jesus did are so important: No miracles => zero indication that Jesus is indeed God. However, if it's true that Jesus did walk on water, or rose from the dead, well, then God must be involved.

Answer (score 0):

Do humans need to prove themselves to ants? There is no need, the mere sheer presence of God would make anyone believe in him, like instinct. You can use this concept if you want.

Comment: That sounds like a power.

Comment: not necessarily, the distinctive recognition of God can be in our DNA since humans have been made, to only trigger when you are near God.